# Adding Firebase SDK somehow breaks facebook login for no apparent reason

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, firebase

I'm running Xcode beta 10, with ios 10 beta, and I got my facebook login working.

if I simply just add

`import Firebase` and `FIRApp.configure()` in my appdelegate, I get the following error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            "fbtrace_id" = CIheVvb2bpQ;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}})
```

This makes virtually no sense to me, I'm not doing anything with firebase yet, not trying to authenticate or track a login, why would simply importing firebase, and configuring it in the appdelegate cause this, and any ideas on how to fix?